# Trying to sum combine a whole lot of columns faster/easier... help appreciated

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to sum columns into groups of 30 (month). Each column is a day. There are almost 2,000 columns

Each row is an individual product and there are about 30,000 of them.

Below is what I am doing to sum them in jupyter.

My question is that is there an easier/faster way to do this without having to do what I did below over 60 more times?

```
Month1 = (df_sales["d_1"] + df_sales["d_2"] + df_sales["d_3"] + df_sales["d_4"]  + df_sales["d_5"]  + df_sales["d_6"]  + df_sales["d_7"]  + df_sales["d_8"]  + df_sales["d_9"]  + df_sales["d_10"] 
    + df_sales["d_11"]  + df_sales["d_12"]  + df_sales["d_13"]  + df_sales["d_14"]  + df_sales["d_15"]  + df_sales["d_16"]  + df_sales["d_17"]  + df_sales["d_18"]  + df_sales["d_19"]  + df_sales["d_20"] 
    + df_sales["d_21"]  + df_sales["d_22"]  + df_sales["d_23"]  + df_sales["d_24"]  + df_sales["d_25"]  + df_sales["d_26"]  + df_sales["d_27"]  + df_sales["d_28"]  + df_sales["d_29"]  + df_sales["d_30"])
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your design. You should make them separate rows, with a `date` column. Then you can group by the month of the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Month1 = df_sales.loc[:, "d_1":"d_30"].sum(axis=1)
```

If every month in your table has 30 days (columns) and you start with the first column, you may perform

```
all_months = pd.concat((df_sales.iloc[:, i:i+30].sum(axis=1) 
                            for i in range(0, df_sales.shape[1], 30)), 
                        axis=1)
```

to obtain the dataframe of all months sums.

Replace

```
range(0, df_sales.shape[1], 30)
```

with

```
range(n, df_sales.shape[1], 30)
```

if your days start in the column `n` (be aware - the first column has number `0`).

Comment: Thanks MarianD! I was trying to get something like this and you showed me just what I was missing :)